# Extjs6 add cordova build has exception

Tags: cordova, extjs6

I added Cordova support to the project following this guide: http://docs.sencha.com/cmd/guides/cordova_phonegap.html#cordova_phonegap_-_emulate, but run build command "sencha app build native" has exception, the execution of other packaging commands, such as "Sencha app build", is not a problem.

Exception tip is:

[image]

Comment: If this still an issue, can you post the contents of AppraiseModel

Comment: @veggirice AppraiseModel code is : Ext.define('GasApp.model.audit.appraise.AppraiseModel',{
    extend : 'Ext.data.Model',
    idProperty : 'id',
    fields : [//slightly...]
});